# When does the space shuttle stop its gravity turn?

Tags: launch, space-shuttle, gravity-turn

I am trying to model the launch of the space shuttle (up to 120km of altitude) from Cape Canaveral, Florida. In order to do so I would need to know when the gravity turn part of the flight starts and stops.

I know that the gravity turn starts 20 seconds after lift off with a pitch angle of 78 degrees. ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20190130172708/https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/shuttle/reference/basics/launch.html) look at left column)

Before that I will assume vertical flight.

I could find [a paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20080048217.pdf) in which figure 5 suggests that the gravity turn for ARES 1 starts 20 seconds after lift off and ends 130 seconds after lift off. But I don't know if the same would be true for the space shuttle.

I could not find any data about when the gravity turn stops for the space shuttle neither could I find at what angle of attack (& pitch) the space shuttle continues. Does anybody have this data?

Comment: This is too partial for even a partial answer, but in Space Shuttle Technical Conference Volume I, page 187 (202 of the pdf) there's a plot of angle of attack, but only for the first two minutes.  https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19850008580.pdf

Comment: Seeing the small angles of attack I would say that the gravity turn already lasts for at least 2 minutes, or does it continue with such a small angle of attack after the gravity turn?

Comment: You might be interested to read this answer and especially its linked references: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23137/how-are-rockets-gimballed-to-produce-a-gravity-turn-for-the-space-shuttle/23139#23139

Comment: I have read it, but I don't really see how it explains the question. It shows the gimbal angles of the engines but I would need to know the angle of attack that results from the trust that no longer goes through the CoM. What is the important part in your post?

Comment: One of the references talks about how the first stage trajectory is designed, I just thought you might be interested.

Comment: You mean the DOLILU software system? It is interesting, but above my capabilities, I would like to start with something that I can solve analytically (taking some rough assumptions and now I am trying to figure out which these assumptions are)

Answer (score 3):

The gravity turn was effectively over about 350 seconds after liftoff.

This can be seen in the graph of flight path angle vs. time.

[image]

(This is from a study of heads-up vs heads-down ascents, but the answer is the same for both).

Source: [A Study to Evaluate STS Heads-up Ascent Trajectory Performance](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19880006438/downloads/19880006438.pdf)

Comment: A gravity turn is defined by two things: 1) Thrust is not used to change the spacecraft's direction, and 2) During the initial ascent phase the vehicle can *maintain* a low or even zero angle of attack. The relative "flight path angle" is the difference between the vehicle's velocity vector (not its orientation) and the horizontal vector. **This chart is not an answer to the question** without a good explanation (and reference) that explains how one can obtain the angle of attack and the amount of thrust used to change direction from the flight path angle.